# Как развернуть однонаправленный связанный список?

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Подскажите, как реализовать операцию обращения списка (reverse) в однонаправленном связанном списке?

Answer (score 9):

Бежишь по списку, первому элементу в поле `next` указываешь `null`, а каждому последующему в `next` предыдущий элемент

Answer (score 5):

Для С++, в котором однонаправленный список реализован классом `forward_list`, достаточно вызвать функцию-член `reverse()` :)

Для С - что-то вроде

```
struct Node
{
    //...
    struct Node * next;
};

void reverse(struct Node ** head)
{
    if (*head == NULL) return;
    struct Node * curr, *next, *prev = NULL;
    curr = *head;
    while(curr)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    *head = prev;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Идиома подцепления элемента `node` в *начало* односвязного списка `list` элементарна и состоит из двух действий

```
node->next = list;
list = node;
```

Все, что надо сделать в данном случае - это пробежаться по исходному списку и последовательно перецепить все его элементы в начало нового списка. Полученный в результате список будет обращением исходного списка

```
Node *reverse_list(Node *list)
{
  Node *reversed_list = NULL;

  for (Node *node = list, *next_node; node != NULL; node = next_node)
  {
    next_node = node->next;
    node->next = reversed_list;
    reversed_list = node;
  }

  return reversed_list;
}
```

---

В качестве заметки на полях: это одна из тех довольно часто встречающихся ситуаций, когда в языках С и С++ ощущается нехватка операции "сдвигающего присваивания", т.е. некоей компактно записываемой операции

```
a <- b <- c <- d
```

эквивалентной

```
(a = b, b = c, c = d)
```