# Теория по односвязному списку

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Здравствуйте.

Довольно часто на собеседованиях или же в тестовых заданиях (для прохождения на стажировку, например) задается вопрос об *односвязных списках*.

Например, дают задачу, в которой необходимо развернуть односвязный список за О(n) времени. Так вот, как это сделать? Можно ли просто переопределить ссылки? Т.е. сделать за 1 итерацию так, чтобы не **A->B**, а **A<-B** ?

Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример? 
*Заранее благодарю*

Comment: Догадка правильная, в чём именно проблема?

Comment: Получается, что я понятия не имею, как это реализовать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как развернуть однонаправленный связанный список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая ссылка из гугла.

```
void reverse(OneWayList list){
    OneWayList.Node node = list.head;
    OneWayList.Node previous = null;
    while(node != null){
         //next item
         OneWayList.Node tmp = node.next;
        //swap items
        node.next = previous;
        previous = node;
        list.head = node;
        //next item
        node = tmp;
    }
}
```

[Отсюда](http://dolzhenko.blogspot.com.by/2012/11/linked-list.html?m=1)

Comment: И, да, @Schepalin, учитесь гуглить

Answer (score 5):

Ну так становитесь на первый элемент, и идя по списку, у каждого разворачиваете указатель на предыдущий узел, из которого вы только что пришли. Понятно, что у самого первого указатель обнуляется, а заголовок списка теперь указывает на узел, который был последним. Вот и `O(n)`.