# Список, написать метод Reverse

Tags: c#, список

Добрый день, такое задание :

> Написать класс, реализующий односвязный список. Класс должен содержать
>   методы Push (добавление элемента в начало списка), Pop (извлечение
>   элемента из начала списка). Также он должен переопределять
>   унаследованный метод Print , возвращающий строковое представление
>   списка. Написать метод Reverse , обращающий порядок следования
>   элементов спис- ка. Написать программу, использующую класс.

Проблема в методе реверс. Как я сделал :

```
public void Reverse()
{
    if (head == null)
        throw new ListUnderflow();
    StringBuilder PrintList = new StringBuilder();
    Node temp = head;


    while (temp != null)
    {
        PrintList.Append(temp.value);
        PrintList.Append(" ");
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = PrintList.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        builder.Append(PrintList[i]);
    }
    string newName = builder.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(newName);

}
```

но так не верно, как мне сказали, что нужно не вывести на экран, а создать новый список, тут вызвать поп , а туда пуш, а что метод должен возвращать тогда ? новый список ?
вот так примерно  :

```
public SinglyLinkedList Reverse()
{
    if (head == null)
        throw new ListUnderflow();
    SinglyLinkedList l2 = new SinglyLinkedList();
    l2.Push(Pop());
    return l2;
}
```

но я не уверен, по этому обратился сюда, можете подсказать ?

Comment: ну я бы предположил что список вообще менять не надо, а только развернуть связи. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509477/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: интересно, спасибо. А вообще расмтаривается как решение выше приведенное предположение о новом списке ?

Comment: обычно метод `reverse` не создаёт нового элемента. А меняет исходный. В некоторых реализациях он _вообще_ ничего не меняет в самом контейнере а просто выставляет флаг, который учитывает при других операциях.

Comment: Я автор задачника, из которого взята эта задача и, по-видимому, преподаватель автора вопроса. У меня к нему меня большая просьба — решайте задачи самостоятельно!

Comment: И да, лучше просто связи перестроить. Вариант с новым списком менее оптимален, но гораздо проще программируется.

Comment: яж не просил все сделать за меня, я попросил помочь и подсказать, думаю в этом нет ничего такого :)

Answer (score 3):

Ниже представлены две простые реализации реверса списка (без проверок, оптимизаций и т.д) - итерационная и рекурсивная:

```
public static void Reverse(ref Node head)
{
    if (head == null) return;

    Node prev = null, current = head, next = null;

    while( current.Next != null )
    {
        next = current.Next;
        current.Next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }

    current.Next = prev;
    head = current;
}

public static void ReverseUsingRecursion(Node head)
{
    if (head == null) return;

    if (head.Next == null)
    {
        newHead = head;
        return;
    }

    ReverseUsingRecursion(head.Next);
    head.Next.Next = head;
    head.Next = null;

}
```

Comment: У топикастера вопрос про односвязные списки, а не про списки на массивах :)

Comment: @PashaPash,  а что здесь может не сработать в односвязном списке? Разве что static лишний.

Comment: @Mirdin код который был в ответе на момент моего комментария мог вполне не сработать в односвязном списке. посмотрите историю правок.

Comment: Моя ошибка. ;-) Не досмотрел условия, но я исправился... Спасибо за коммент @PashaPash