# Cи, односвязные списки и файлы

Tags: c, список, односвязный-список

Задача: 
Дана последовательность действительных чисел a1,a2,..., an( n >= 2 и заранее неизвестно). Если последовательность упорядочена по неубыванию, то оставить её без изменения, иначе получить последовательность an, a(n-1), ...., a1.

В универе дали только линейные списки и функцию fopen (fopen_s) 
Прочитал все топовые статьи из гугла, в списках вроде разобрался, но не понимаю, как решить эту задачу с помощью списков
Помогите пожалуйста именно с идеей или с примерами решений похожих задач

Comment: а тут только линейный списки и нужны. Если вам интересно как развернуть список - то http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509477/Теория-по-односвязному-списку

Answer (score 1):

для разворачивания односвязного списка вам нужно сделать так, чтобы следующий указывал на предыдущий а предыдущий на следующий, при этом новая голова станет хвостом и наоборот - всё просто

написал на С++, перевод в С будет вашим доп. тривиальным заданием

```
/*
o1->o2->o3->o4
o4->o3->o2->o1 // после реверса
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node 
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};

void reverse(node*& head) 
{
    if (head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr)
        return;

    node* prev = nullptr;
    node* next = nullptr;

    while (head)
    {
        next = head->next;      
        head->next = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = next;        
    }
    head = prev;
}

void printList(node* head)
{
    node* tmp = head;
    while (tmp)
    {
        cout << tmp->data << ' ';
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    node a, b, c, d;
    a.data = 1;
    a.next = &b;

    b.data = 2;
    b.next = &c;

    c.data = 3;
    c.next = &d;

    d.data = 4;
    d.next = nullptr;

    node* head = &a;

    printList(head);
    reverse(head);
    printList(head);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, перевел на Си. Но программа все равно не работает.

Comment: @Александр ну значит неправильно перевели, что значит не работает ??

Comment: хотел кинуть код, но с VS что-то случилось. Подожите 10 минут пожалуйста.

Comment: понял свою ошибку, я почему то думал, что cout это просто аналог printf'a в С++. Как правильно перевести цикл while из функции printList?

Comment: @Александр а что там переводить ? цикл while он и в С такой же

Comment: я про  эту строчку: " cout << tmp->data << ' '; ". Как она будет выглядеть в Си?

Comment: @Александр и что там не так ?? поменяйте cout на `printf("%d ", tmp->data);`

Comment: все, остальное совсем элементарно. Вот консоль после запуска - http://imgur.com/a/vOwiH.

Comment: @Александр если сейчас всё работает, помечай ответ как принятый

Comment: дело в том, что она просто переворачивает заданный список не зависимо от того упорядочена последовательность по неубыванию или нет.

Comment: @Александр ну вот подумайте как можно такую проверку сделать