# Развернуть односвязнный список

Tags: c++, список

Как можно его развернуть,  используя O(n) времени и O(1) памяти?

```
strunct Node {
    int payload;
    Node *next;
};
Node* head;
```

Comment: Вместо скриншотов пожалуйста публикуйте код. (А то есть шанс получить фотографию монитора/бумажки с решением)

Comment: я этот вопрос уже 2 раза видел тут)

Comment: по поиску не вижу

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/272/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509477/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 1):

Вставка в начало списка O(1) по времени и по памяти. Поэтому можно сделать так: заведите новый пустой список, обходите старый, вставляя каждый элемент в начало нового. Итого получится как раз O(1) по памяти и O(n) по времени.

Answer (score 1):

Без вставки в новый - просто идете по списку, разворачивая у каждого элемента поле `next` назад, на предыдущий. У бывшего самого первого поле `next` обнуляется, `head` устанавливается на бывший последний элемент.

По сути в общем-то, то же самое, что и вставка в новый..